# FragmentListView with Actionbar Tabs and Pager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview

I am attempting to get a list fragment working within the template generated by android studio for tabs and swiping between them.

The symptoms are that the fragment gets executed once at the start of the activity but never again if the tab is changed.
It never shows up contents (whether start of activity or otherwise).

The boilerplate code is as so:

```
package com.responseapp.android.activity;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.responseapp.android.R;

public class TestActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test2);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test2, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

I have done the following to little success:

```
package com.responseapp.android.ui;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

import com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid;
import com.responseapp.android.R;
import com.responseapp.android.model.Trip;
import com.responseapp.android.ui.authorisation.LoginActivity;
import com.responseapp.android.ui.trips.CreateTripActivity;

import java.util.Locale;

import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.ActionBarPullToRefresh;
import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        ActiveAndroid.initialize(this);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("com.responseapp.app.SHARED", 0);

        boolean loggedIn = sharedPref.getBoolean("LOGGED_IN", false);

        if (!loggedIn) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        }

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        getActionBar().setTitle("Response");

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (actionBar != null) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("com.responseapp.app.SHARED", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("LOGGED_IN", false);
            editor.commit();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_new_trip) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateTripActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Called when a tab enters the selected state.
     *
     * @param tab The tab that was selected
     * @param ft  A {@link android.app.FragmentTransaction} for queuing fragment operations to execute
     *            during a tab switch. The previous tab's unselect and this tab's select will be
     *            executed in a single transaction. This FragmentTransaction does not support
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        System.out.println("FRAGMENT TAPPED!");
    }

    /**
     * Called when a tab exits the selected state.
     *
     * @param tab The tab that was unselected
     * @param ft  A {@link android.app.FragmentTransaction} for queuing fragment operations to execute
     *            during a tab switch. This tab's unselect and the newly selected tab's select
     *            will be executed in a single transaction. This FragmentTransaction does not
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    /**
     * Called when a tab that is already selected is chosen again by the user.
     * Some applications may use this action to return to the top level of a category.
     *
     * @param tab The tab that was reselected.
     * @param ft  A {@link android.app.FragmentTransaction} for queuing fragment operations to execute
     *            once this method returns. This FragmentTransaction does not support
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            String type = position == 0 ? "all" : "managed";
            System.out.println("GOT THIS FAR");
            return TripListFragment.newInstance(type);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.all_trips_title).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.managed_trips_title).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A trip list fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class TripListFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_TYPE = "all";

        /**
         * The fragment's ListView/GridView.
         */
        private AbsListView mListView;

        /**
         * The Adapter which will be used to populate the ListView/GridView with
         * Views.
         */
        private ListAdapter mAdapter;

        private PullToRefreshLayout mPullToRefreshLayout;

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static TripListFragment newInstance(String sectionType) {
            TripListFragment fragment = new TripListFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_SECTION_TYPE, sectionType);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public TripListFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            System.out.println("BEING CALLED");

            if(ARG_SECTION_TYPE == "all") {
                mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Trip.TripItem>(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, android.R.id.text1, Trip.getAllAsItems(0));
            } else {
                mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Trip.TripItem>(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, android.R.id.text1, Trip.getManagedAsItems(0));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_triplist, container, false);

            mPullToRefreshLayout = new PullToRefreshLayout(container.getContext());

            // Set the adapter
            mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            System.out.println("VIEW:"+view.toString());
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Trip.TripItem trip = (Trip.TripItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            HomeActivity.onFragmentInteraction(1, trip.id);
        }
    }

    private static void onFragmentInteraction(int i, int id) {

    }


}
```

The difference being the fragment class embedded in the main class.
In the boilerplate:

```
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

In my code:

```
/**
 * A trip list fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class TripListFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_TYPE = "all";

    /**
     * The fragment's ListView/GridView.
     */
    private AbsListView mListView;

    /**
     * The Adapter which will be used to populate the ListView/GridView with
     * Views.
     */
    private ListAdapter mAdapter;

    private PullToRefreshLayout mPullToRefreshLayout;

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static TripListFragment newInstance(String sectionType) {
        TripListFragment fragment = new TripListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_SECTION_TYPE, sectionType);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public TripListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        System.out.println("BEING CALLED");

        if(ARG_SECTION_TYPE == "all") {
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Trip.TripItem>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, android.R.id.text1, Trip.getAllAsItems(0));
        } else {
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Trip.TripItem>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, android.R.id.text1, Trip.getManagedAsItems(0));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_triplist, container, false);

        mPullToRefreshLayout = new PullToRefreshLayout(container.getContext());

        // Set the adapter
        mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        System.out.println("VIEW:"+view.toString());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Trip.TripItem trip = (Trip.TripItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        HomeActivity.onFragmentInteraction(1, trip.id);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.